# Meteor / Iron Router external redirection

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

So I'm creating a basic vanity URL system, where I can have `http://myURL.com/v/some-text`, grab an item from the database and redirect to a specific URL based on whether or not the client is mobile/desktop and other features.

I usually build Facebook apps, so in the case of desktop they would be redirected to a Facebook URL, otherwise on mobile I can just use normal routes.

Is there a way to redirect from Iron Router on the server-side to an external website?

```
this.route('vanity',{
    path: '/v/:vanity',
    data: function(){
        var vanity = Vanity.findOne({slug:this.params.vanity});

        // mobile / desktop detection

        if(vanity){
            if(mobile){
                // Redirect to vanity mobile link
            }else{
                // Redirect to vanity desktop link
            }
        }else{
            Router.go('/');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a simple 302-based redirect using a server-side route:

```
Router.route('/google/:search', {where: 'server'}).get(function() {
  this.response.writeHead(302, {
    'Location': "https://www.google.com/#q=" + this.params.search
  });
  this.response.end();
});
```

If you navigate to http://localhost:3000/google/dogs, you should be redirected to https://www.google.com/#q=dogs.

Note that if you would like to respond with a 302 to **all** request verbs (GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, etc.) you can write it like this:

```
Router.route('/google/:search', function() {
  this.response.writeHead(302, {
    'Location': "https://www.google.com/#q=" + this.params.search
  });
  this.response.end();
}, {where: 'server'});
```

This may be what you want if you are doing redirects for SEO purposes.

Comment: Does this still work? I tried this and I just got 'route does not exists'. Using iron router 1.0.9

Comment: Perhaps you didn't add the route under your `server` directory? I just validated both versions for GET requests using IR 1.0.9. To replicate: (1) create an empty project, (2) remove all files, (3) add `iron:router`, (4) add a file `server/main.js` with one of the above examples, (5) start meteor an navigate to the route from your browser.

Comment: Is it possible to do 302 redirect in client side?